# CosmosDB with EF Core: integer partition key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, ef-core-6.0

I'm new to Cosmos DB and I'm trying to understand if I'm able to use an integer partion key for a CosmosDB (SQL API) document along with EF Core 6 Cosmos DB provider. In my first iteration, I did *not* use EF Core, and it appears I was successfully able to do this. I can write documents like this:
[image]
Two things to note:

1. "organizationId" is the partition key for this collection
2. In the documents shown, the values are 1 and 6. There are no quotation marks, and so I'm lead to believe that I've succesfully written documents with an integer key value.

Everything worked as I expected before I attempted to introduce EF Core 6 into my (ASP.NET Core 6) project. This is also supported by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview which states:

> The partition key value (For example: "Andrew"). The partition key
> value can be of string or numeric types.

I was then able to successfully query this data by doing:

```
       int organizationId = organizationIdParameter;

        using (FeedIterator<QuestionnaireResponse> setIterator = cont.GetItemLinqQueryable<QuestionnaireResponse>(requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
        {
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(organizationId),
        })
          
         .ToFeedIterator<QuestionnaireResponse>())
        {
            //Asynchronous query execution
            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item2.UserId);
                }
            }
        }
```

The key here is:

```
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(organizationId),
```

I'm passing to the PartitionKey constructor an integer, and I get expected results.

But now that I've added EF Core 6, when I query with the following:

```
int organizationId = organizationIdParameter;
            var toReturn = _cosmosDbContext.QuestionnaireResponses.WithPartitionKey(organizationId.ToString());
```

(I .ToString() because WithPartitionKey requires a string parameter)
I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type of the partition key
> property 'OrganizationId' on 'QuestionnaireResponse' is 'int'. All
> partition key properties need to be strings or have a string value
> converter.'

If it's relevant, in my OnModelCreating:

```
            builder.Entity<QuestionnaireResponse>()
.ToContainer("QuestionnaireResponses").HasPartitionKey(q => q.OrganizationId);
```

HasPartitionKey accepts the OrganizationId property which is of type int.

So I'm wondering:

- Is it the case that CosmosDB currently supports using an integer as a partition key, but the EF Core CosmosDB provider does not support this scenario?
- Is there any workaround that would allow me to use an integer partition key with the EF Core CosmosDB provider? Possibly with the string value converter suggested in the exception?
- Does it make sense for me to simply store my partition key as a string instead? Are there any implications to that as far as document size or performance that aren't ideal?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

**Is it the case that CosmosDB currently supports using an integer as a partition key, but the EF Core CosmosDB provider does not support this scenario?**

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), Partition key only contain `String` values - or any data type that should preferably be converted into a `String`, as mentioned in the above document,

> The partition key property can be of any type as long as it is
> converted to `string`

**Is there any workaround that would allow me to use an integer partition key with the EF Core CosmosDB provider? Possibly with the string value converter suggested in the exception?**

To convert `int` to `string` you can use [Built-in value convertor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#built-in-converters).

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()  
.Property(e => e.propertythatcovert)  
.HasConversion<string>();
```

**Does it make sense for me to simply store my partition key as a string instead? Are there any implications to that as far as document size or performance that aren't ideal?**

As mentioned, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey), It mostly preferred that partition key always should be in string type.
As the [JSON specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-6) specifies some problems due to immutable and migrations required on partition key column.

Comment: Thankks for the response - I updated my question to point to documentation from MS that states "The partition key value can be of string or numeric types." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview - essentially it seems as though the string-only requirement in the EF Core provider is tighter than the requirement of the DB itself. I'd be curious to understand if the reason for this discrepency is, as you said, because we're advised to use strings only, though we're allowed to use ints.

Comment: While numeric values are supported (keep in mind that the REST API specs need to be backward compatible) it is preferable always to use strings. As indicated by the JSON specification link, using numbers can lead to unknowns when parsing JSON in different languages, reading that numeric value in a NodeJS environment or C# when the values go beyond the safe limit might have issues.